# JavaScript Duplicate Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, duplicates, frontend, session-cookies

I'm using the Hapi framework for a Node.js application, and the Hapi framework comes with its own Cookie management tools, which i'm using for authentication.

The framework then sets a cookie named session, with a json value encoded to base64. The domain is set to example.com (not .example.com)

Now, the problem lies when i attempt to edit this cookie client-side, by doing the following

```
document.cookie = 'session=' + btoa(JSON.stringify(_decoded)) + "; path=/; domain=example.com";
```

This actually sets a duplicate cookie with the domain '.example.com'

I haven't asked Javascript to prepend the dot, and i cant seem to get rid of it.

I'm assuming that it is because of this dot, that the cookie is being duplicated. How do i set the domain without it automatically prepending a dot?

**EDIT**

I've given up on trying to remove the leading dot, and instead am trying to delete the old cookie and then create a new one. However i still end up with duplicate cookies!

1. Navigate to /login and enter login details
2. Redirected to /account and cookie set by server (WITHOUT Leading Dot)
3. Execute Javascript to delete and re-create cookie
4. 1 cookie now exists and it has a Leading Dot before the domain

The above behaviour is good, however the following also happens, which is bad

1. Navigate to /login and enter login details
2. Redirected to /account and cookie set by server (WITHOUT Leading Dot)
3. Navigate to /example
4. Execute Javascript to delete and re-create cookie
5. 2 cookies now exists, one with the leading dot(created by JS) and one without (created by server)

The code i'm using is

```
API.Session = {
    Encoded : function () { return document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)session\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1")},
    Decoded : function () { return JSON.parse(atob(this.Encoded()))},
    Update : function (_decoded) { 
        document.cookie = 'session=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        document.cookie = 'session=' + btoa(JSON.stringify(_decoded)) + "; path=/; domain=example.com;";      
    }
}

API.Helpers.ShowAdvancedOptions = function () {
    var s = API.Session.Decoded()
    s.ShowAdvancedOptions = true
    API.Session.Update(s)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with a similar issue, this was eventually solved by dropping the domain property altogether. See [other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46026859/7754471)

Answer (score 0):

Is by some chance the original cookie already present in this?

```
btoa(JSON.stringify(_decoded))
```

Cause from:
[document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

document.cookie is defined as:

> a string containing a semicolon-separated list of all cookies

So it seems to me you are adding a new semicolon-separated value (new cookie) to that list (without removing the original cookie)

Ok, it's not that, have you tried this?

[link](http://answers.elteacher.info/questions/post/2471517/duplicate-cookies-domain-property-automatically-prepending-ask-question.html)

Sounds like the same problem you described

Comment: The original cookie is "session=eyJpZCI6IjVhYWZhYjE2MDRiYTVjZmQ3NmIyNDhmZDM3ODNiNmE1In0=", the _decoded variable is derived from decoding the base64 into a JSON object and then adding a property to it

Comment: @Michael - see the edit, sounds to me like the thing that is bothering you

Comment: Thank you, i'm slightly confused by your link. Its my question - word for word - on another site, and the answer seems unrelated?