# JavaScript Cookie absolutely refuses to be deleted

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, hapi.js

This is related to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025255/javascript-duplicate-cookies), i'm asking a new question as i've narrowed down the problem and the original question was getting rather convoluted.

In a nutshell, i have a cookie that refuses to be deleted!

My server sets the cookie "**session=abc; domain=example.com; path=/;**"

I want to edit this cookie client-side, so lets say i want to change abc to xyz then i run the following code

```
document.cookie = "session=xyz; domain=example.com; path=/;"
```

Now, when i inspect the cookies i actually now have the following two cookies (**note the leading dot**):

```
"session=abc; domain=example.com; path=/;"
"session=xyz; domain=.example.com; path=/;"
```

I quickly gave up trying to force my new cookie to drop the dot, and instead opted to delete the existing cookie before setting a new cookie.

However, this:

```
document.cookie = 'session=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

and this:

```
document.cookie = 'session=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=example.com;';
```

Both do absolutely nothing

How on earth am i supposed to delete a cookie, when i can't even get the domains to match up?

**NB**

Whilst writing this question, things have gotten more complicated! I have just noticed that the above behaviour only happens on a specific page, if i attempt to delete the server's cookie from another page it disappears without a fuss

**To add insult to injury**
This actually works as expected in IE/Edge

Comment: Brainfuck is the name of a programming language. Removed the tag.

Comment: I know you don't want to use a library unless absolutely necessary, but perhaps looking at JS-Cookie would help in some way: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: @jswebb Thanks, yes i think a library might be the only way forward, thanks for the link - looks like exactly what i might need

Comment: @jswebb considering js-cookie is only around 150 lines of code, i just ran a quick test by copy-pasting it into chromes dev tools and then calling Cookies.remove('session') and it worked a treat. If you want to post this as an answer, i'm more than happy to accept it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you don't want to use dependencies unless necessary, but JS-Cookie is an extremely lightweight, extensively tested library that is cross compatible; it shouldn't affect performance and could be exactly what you're looking for

Here's a link to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This was solved by removing the domain altogether!

```
document.cookie = 'session=xyz; path=/; domain=;";
```

Hope this helps someone else, as this has been an absolute bitch to diagnose

**EDIT**

So in a cruel twist of fate, this does indeed fix the issue for chrome and firefox, but you guessed it - IE/Edge is now throwing the toys out of the pram!

I give up

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery cookie library instead of accessing document.cookie directly https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Then just use it like `jQuery.cookie('session','xyz',{ path: '/' });`

Comment: Not everyone uses jQuery.

Comment: Wait, waaaat? Using JavaScript isn't a good practice compared to 3rd party libraries? I'm sorry, but this isn't only not an answer, but also a very bad perspective of usage of external libraries.

Comment: I didnt tell about using vanilla javascript, i was talking about editing document.cookie directly, any way i will edit my answer if I hurt your javascript feelings :(

Comment: jQuery might have saved me some grey hairs, but i try and only use libraries when i absolutely have to

Comment: Referring to links isn't a smart move.. The link can be broken. Add the needed code to prevent this answer from becoming absolete

Comment: Regardless of the 3rd party issue, this still does not address the problem. It's merely a general recommendation for a workflow - and does not belong as an answer, especially given your ability to comment.